# Installation failed - SAP Adaptive Server Enterprise 16.0 SP03

Tags: installation, sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

I am try to install SAP Adaptive Server Enterprise 16.0 SP03 (evaluate version).
I have a win 10 OS. Installation show error message when try install. Any idea why it is fail?

[image]

I shared logs files [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vBCVX4lM1kNrprhqgxuiKcczn2PJYAfE/view)

Comment: this snippet from the log file mentions two other log files that may have more details; it may also be necessary to peruse the entire `ASE_suite.log` file for all such references (to other log files with details) in order to piece together the bigger picture; at this point we don't have enough info to determine the root cause of the failure; unfortunately SAP is not very good at providing clear, concise explanations for why a process fails ... you need to go digging through an assortment of logs for the details :-(

Comment: Thaks for your comment. I have shared the log files in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vBCVX4lM1kNrprhqgxuiKcczn2PJYAfE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: main log only mentions the same 2x log files in your question/snippet; those 2x log files list several non-fatal errors with the windows `PATH` variable being too long (not sure what the limit is for windows `PATH` variable ...?); there are also a few mentions of registry mods failing ... looks like attempt to place null values/strings into some fields in the registry; the registry entries look related to setting up new (windows) services related to ASE; how did you run the installer? did you provide answers to the GUI or did you use a resource file? ...

Comment: with only the log files to look at it appears (to) me that most of the installation was successful; the 'fatal' errors appear to be related to creating a new ASE dataserver; do you have a background working with ASE or is this something new for you?  my personal preference is to use the installer to **just** install the software and then I manually create a new ASE dataserver (vs having the installer create a default dataserver); some ideas on next steps ...

Comment: verify no new (windows) services were created (and are running?); if created, make sure they are stopped, then drop them; then try the installation again but this time do not have the installer create a default dataserver ... the downside to this is that you now need to run some manual steps to create a new dataserver ... which is a whole 'nother issue; if you still have problems I'd suggest opening a case with SAP support (if you have a support contract) otherwise consider posting a question at community.sap.com where some tech spt folks may see your post and be able to help

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso 
I am try installing from setup.exe file. I undertand it is GUI installer.
I not saw any options for excluiding the creations a new ASE dataserver.
I will try checking the OS's servives and stop any  related with sybase and to installa one more time.
I do not have support contact. 
I am try installing evaluate version.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved!

The problem was the PATH environment variable. When I tried to register a new SAP path it exceeded the OS limit.

I removed some unimportant paths and the installation was successful.

Thanks @markp-fuso